# Cómo filtrar un número de un template en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, filtro

estoy construyendo un filtro de precios y necesito comparar el valor que va variando del input del precio con el valor que se encuentre en la card que contiene la información de los precios del .json..
Tengo cargado el .json en un template a través de un fetch.

```
const fetchData = async() => {
try{
    const res = await fetch("./productos.json");
    const data = await res.json(); 
    // console.log(data); 
    mostrarProductos(data);
    detectarBotones(data);  
    // filtroCategorias(data);
    priceFilter(data);
} catch(error){
    console.log(error);
 }
}
```

Aqui cargo los productos al template

```
const mostrarProductos = (data) => {

const template = d.getElementById("template-productos").content;

const fragment = d.createDocumentFragment(); 

//Recorremos Data; 

data.forEach(producto => {
    // img
    template.querySelector("img").setAttribute("src", producto.imageUrl);
    // title
    template.querySelector("h6").textContent = producto.title;
    // price
    template.querySelector("span").textContent = producto.price;
    // Description
    template.querySelectorAll("p")[0].textContent = producto.description;
    // Categoria
    template.querySelectorAll("p")[1].textContent = producto.categoria;
    // Button
    template.querySelector("button").dataset.id = producto.id;
    // Clonamos
    const clone = template.cloneNode(true); 

    fragment.appendChild(clone); 

})
contenedorProductos.appendChild(fragment); 
}
```

Y lo que quiero hacer es filtrar dependiendo de como vaya variando el input a continuación:

```
const priceFilter = (productos) => {

const priceInput = d.querySelector(".price-filter");
const priceValue = d.querySelector(".price-value"); 

// Precio máximo
let maxPrice  = productos.map((item) => item.price);
maxPrice = Math.max(...maxPrice);
priceInput.value = maxPrice; 
priceInput.max = maxPrice; 
priceInput.min = 0; 
priceValue.textContent = `$${maxPrice}`;


priceInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
    const value = +(priceInput.value); 
    priceValue.textContent = `$${value}`;
     let newStore =  productos.filter(producto => producto.price <= value)

   let cards = [...d.querySelectorAll(".card")]; 
})
}
```

Hasta acá llegué.. en "cards" estoy seleccionando cada tarjeta del template.. y después no sé como hacer para comparar el valor que está cargado dentro de precio.. no sé como seleccionar el precio que está dentro de una etiqueta span.. aunque no sé si eso me lo toma como número o como texto..

```
<template id="template-productos">
<div class="card col-3" id="card-container" >
  <img src="" class="card-img-top py-4" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <h6 class="card-title">Generic Title</h6>
    <p class="card-text text-center">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <p>category</p>
    <p >$<span>0</span></p>
    <button  class="btn btn-primary ">Add to Card</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

este es el template en donde se van almacenando los producto que se van cargando..
Necesito comparar el valor de entrada de "value" con lo que se encuentre en la etiqueta  que se carga dinámicamente..